# Adding a condition to a set of elements in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

With Vue.js I've made three inputs (years, months, days) and I need show an error message for the empty inputs (one or more),

So there are three conditions that I need to write in one line of code instead of using v-if directive for each single one,

```
<script>
 export default {
  data() {
    return {
      years: null,
      months: null,
      days: null,
    };
  },
 }
 </script>

<template>
 <form action="">
  <div class="inputs">
   <div>
     <label for="Day">Day</label>
     <input type="number" placeholder="DD" id="Day" v-model="years" />
     <p class="empty-error">This field is required</p>
   </div>
   <div>
    <label for="Month">Month</label>
    <input type="number" placeholder="MM" id="Month" v-model="months" />
    <p class="empty-error">This field is required</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="Year">Year</label>
    <input type="number" placeholder="YYYY" id="Year" v-model="days" />
    <p class="empty-error">This field is required</p>
  </div>
 </div>
   <div class="submit">
     <div class="submit-btn">
      <img src="../assets/images/icon-arrow.svg" alt="" />
     </div>
  </div>
 </form>
</template>
```

Inside create() method I've tried to define a var which is inputs and made a loop to check if they any input is empty but it only works if all inputs were (not only one).

SO that I need to know can I write the code which its logic is, "If any input is empty show the error message element after it".

Comment: Which version of Vue.js? A computed property representing the validity of your models would be a simple approach

Comment: Hello there, I'm using Vue.js 3

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the code for your component(s). How are you tracking the input field values (are you using `v-model` or something else)? Have you tried anything yet? If so, what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use watchers.

Your form will be this like this:

```html
<form action="">
  <div class="inputs">
    <div>
      <label for="Day">Day</label>
      <input type="number" placeholder="DD" id="Day" v-model="years" />
      <p class="empty-error">{{ required_years }}</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="Month">Month</label>
      <input type="number" placeholder="MM" id="Month" v-model="months" />
      <p class="empty-error">{{ required_months }}</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="Year">Year</label>
      <input type="number" placeholder="YYYY" id="Year" v-model="days" />
      <p class="empty-error">{{ required_days }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="submit">
    <div class="submit-btn">
      <img src="../assets/images/icon-arrow.svg" alt="" />
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

And in the script you can use watchers like this:

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      years: "",
      months: "",
      days: "",
      required_years: "",
      required_months: "",
      required_days: "",
    };
  },
  watch: {
    months: function (new_value, old_value) {
      if (new_value == "") {
        this.required_months = "This field is required";
      } else {
        this.required_months = "";
      }
    },
    years: function (new_value, old_value) {
      if (new_value == "") {
        this.required_years = "This field is required";
      } else {
        this.required_years = "";
      }
    },
    days: function (new_value, old_value) {
      if (new_value == "") {
        this.required_days = "This field is required";
      } else {
        this.required_days = "";
      }
    },
  },
};
```